# How to perform click on Image Button Link in Adf using Java Script

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I have an **oracle.adf.RichCommandImageLink** type of component, I want to perform click event on the component using javascript. I am using below code to identify the component.

> window.comp = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent("pt1:pt_s2:login");

Thanks in Advance !